# Using SCIM in WS02 identity server

Tags: java, wso2, identity, wso2-identity-server

I have downloaded WS02 Identity Server (version 3.2.3) and installed it on Windows. I want to explore SCIM support provided by WS02 IS. However, I could not find any information on it. Is there a developer's guide that gives more details on the SOAP/REST endpoints exposed by WS02 IS for SCIM?

I have gone through the documentation for WS02 IS, but it is more of an admin/user guide.

I am looking for more details on how to use SCIM support in WS02 IS to manage users and groups.

Answer (score 1):

There is a presentation "Standardizing Identity Provisioning with SCIM" on the wso2 website that may help: [link](http://wso2.org/library/webinars/2012/01/standardizing-identity-provisioning-scim).

I think this is the same presentation but on [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3cYuMZaEddQ)

Answer (score 0):

SCIM support is only available from WSO2 Identity Server 4.0.0.